# Installing Fonttools with pip on MacOS

Tags: macos, python, pip

I'm trying to install FontTools. I installed it with pip.

```
pip install fonttools
```

When I try to reinstall it, I have this message so it looks like it's already installed.

```
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (3.42.0)
```

But each time I try to run `fonttools` or `pyftsubset`, I get this message error

```
-bash: fonttools: command not found
```

Searching the solution, I found it could be related to `$PATH`. I tried adding the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` in `$PATH` but with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools/issues/912#issuecomment-367689064). I uninstalled fonttools and reinstalled it using this command

```
python -m pip install --user fonttools
```

And I added this in my `.bash_profile` file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Python/2.7/bin
```